# How do I emulate I2C_RDWR ioctl with the help of I2C_SMBUS ioctl?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c, smbus

The underlying driver on my system does not support I2C_RDWR ioctl. It only supports I2C_SMBUS. My requirement is to support single message  I2C_RDWR ioctl with I2C_SMBUS either in user or kernel space.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it theoretical requirement or you have real I²C slave device connected? If the latter is true, have you tried something? What went wrong?

Comment: It depends on the format of the transaction you want to perform. If it doesn't fit one of the formats supported by the I2C_SMBUS ioctl, then you are out of luck.